# How to use Regex to filter file names in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

```
 Regex reg = new Regex(@"^[0-9]*\.wav");
  Stack<string> wavefiles= new Stack<string>(Directory.GetFiles("c:\\WaveFiles", "*.wav").Where(path => reg.IsMatch(path)));
```

what I am trying to do in the above code is to get all the wave files with names having only digits. for example "123.wav"

when I try the above code it does not return any files ?

any ideas what is wrong with my code?

Comment: `Regex(@"^[0-9]+\.wav$");` but i think this won't solve your problem.

Comment: Generally with these things you want to break down your regex one step at a time.  Take out the [0-9]* and see if it works.  You might also want a $ at the end of your regex to ensure you don't get files like 23.waver...

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it without Regex

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\WaveFiles", "*.wav")
            .Where(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).All(char.IsDigit));
```

Comment: Very elegant and creative, I like it! Also a lot more readable for people who are less familiar with regex. Do you happen to know anything about the difference in performance though?

Comment: @FredKleuver Most costly part is the Disk IO involved in `Directory.GetFiles`. So, I don't think you can see any difference between two.

Comment: If you're using a `Where`, you may as well use `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles`.

Answer (score 1):

`Directory.GetFiles` gives you a list of file names including the paths. You are trying to match your regex on results like this:
"C:\WaveFiles\123.wav".

You are expecting this entire string to start with a digit, and then contain only digits up to the ".wav" part, which of course won't match any of your files.

You might also want to replace `[0-9]` by `\d` for digits but that's a matter of preference.

Try this:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^\d+\.wav");

string[] waveFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\WaveFiles", "*.wav");

Stack<string> filesWithOnlyDigits = new Stack<string>(waveFilePaths 
    .Where(path => reg.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(path))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex string is a little off, but not bad. I'd really do

```
Regex(@"^\d+\.wav$");
```

Which will match all file names that have one or more digits as their name and wav as their extension.

The real issue here is that all of your strings start with `C:\WaveFiles\` which is why your regex is failing.

You will want to add a line to get the filename from the full path:

```
Path.GetFilename(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex reg = new Regex(@"^[0-9]*.wav");
                wavefiles = new Stack(Directory.GetFiles(FolderName, "*.wav").Where(path => reg.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(path))));

Comment: **1)** `[0-9]` or `[0-9]+`  **?**  **2)**  `.` or `\.` **?**  **3)** I guess this is not an answer. Edit your question and add this code there.